# Is there any engines for fetching twitter xml or json output?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

Is there any engines for fetching twitter xml or json output? I wonder if there is such components in popular engines or something like that.

Comment: `NSURLConnection` and `NSXMLParser` have been available since the first iPhone SDK was released.  iOS 5.0 includes `NSJSONSerialization`, and there are at least two open-source Objective-C JSON parsers for older versions of iOS.  Did you have a specific question?

Comment: I know about this methods. I was asking about specific libraries for twitter output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project called Tweetero: http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/
And it has BSD License, so I think you might find some interesting code there.

Comment: Thanx, but I have not found any source code there.

Comment: You have to go to Source section and there you will have svn address. Use can use any svn client to download the source.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awesome JSON library for objective-c

https://github.com/stig/json-framework

For XML i user a simple library called TBXML

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Cheers!